# Changing Text dynamically for different classes clicked - Jquery lightbox plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using [jquery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) in a project, and I want to customize it a bit...
Basically, I'm adding a title to the top of each pop-out lightbox enlarged image. Now the Title will change depending on the class of the anchor tag that contains the image. I have 3 classes,and each class will have different text for the title.

Now here is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwJQt/6/) to see what I'm trying...

As you can see, when the lightbox animation is activated, the 'My Text' title does not change when going to an image of different a-tag class...

Any suggestions? Look at my JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) instead of .is. Jquery hasClass is a boolean type

```
$(function() {
   $('#gallery a').lightBox();

   var A = "Text for A";
   var B = "Text for B";
   var C = "Text for C";   
   $('#gallery').find('a').click(function (){



   if ($(this).haClass('classA')) {
          $('#lightbox-title-data-span1').html(A);
        };
   if ($(this).haClass('classB')) {
             $('#lightbox-title-data-span1').html(B);
        };

   if ($(this).haClass('classC')) {
             $('#lightbox-title-data-span1').html(C);
        };



       })

});​
```

Comment: Thank you, that works but there is one problem remaining...you'll see that changing between classes only works when actually clicking on the relative class' thumbnail(that is what you defined right). However, when using the lightbox next and previous functions/buttons paging through the images, it does not change between the classes, it keeps the text of one class only throughout...Any help?

Comment: Hi again... I tried everything I can think of, but cannot get it to work...this is my latest attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/KwJQt/34/ -  Any suggestions?